# Excel Power Query not Working on Colleagues Computer

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

My excel power query I built is not working on computers other than mine.

When other people try to refresh the query on the sheet (which is stored on SharePoint) the following error shows up:

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your version of excel is the same as your colleague.

Anyway, from the error message I can read notesSort... is it a sorted column on the fly or the effective name of the field?

Try to remove the column from the Advance Editor and analyse what is going on. Test on your colleague computer to check if it's working.

Hope that helps!